# Reading files and asking for an input on a new line

Tags: ruby

I understand how to open and then print the content of the file. I would like to understand how to ask a second question on a new line after the txt file has been printed.

The code below prints the output of the text file, then on the same line, asks "*Type the file name again:*"

```
filename = ARGV.first

txt = open(filename)

puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"
print txt.read

print "Type the filename again: "
file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read
```

I would like this question to be printed on a new line after the txt file has been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use puts and not print.
The difference is that puts add a new line at the end of the output.

```
filename = ARGV.first

txt = open(filename)

puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"

puts txt.read // Changed Line

print "Type the filename again: "
file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp

txt_again = open(file_again)

puts txt_again.read //Changed Line
```

Comment: Ah of course.  Now I see that.  Thanks @MarcleRodrigues